# What does "envelope" mean in mathematics in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

I stumbled upon this sentence:

> Compared with the **envelope** [some mathematical formula] of the sinusoidal term, [some other mathematical formula] decays very fast, and the overall response is similar to the response of a second-order system.
> https://repository.bilkent.edu.tr/server/api/core/bitstreams/b8fd1d02-2784-44d3-9574-240997087a31/content

What does "envelope" mean in this context? Obviously, it is not this:
[image]
Now, dictionary.com provides the definition that "envelope" in mathematics means:

> 4. Geometry. a curve or surface tangent to each member of a set of curves or surfaces.

However, it seems to me it is not that either.
So, what does "envelope" mean in this context?

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)) *In physics and engineering, the **envelope** of an oscillating signal is a smooth curve outlining its extremes. The envelope thus generalizes the concept of a constant amplitude into an instantaneous amplitude.*

Comment: You should consult a mathematical dictionary or encyclopedia for questions about the meaning of mathematical terms. A regular dictionary will not necessarily give mathematical terminology (and if it does, it will often be a simplification).

Comment: @StuartF Which dictionary would you recommend me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An envelope is a container, or a set of containing conditions.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envelope) has

> the set of operating parameters that exists within these limits

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/envelope) is closer, having

> *telecommunications*
> the outer shape of a modulated wave, formed by the peaks of successive cycles of the carrier wave

Comment: Yeah, it could be the Collins'es definition in telecommunications.